# Is there any way to cache multiple files in PWA?

Tags: javascript, caching, filesystems, progressive-web-apps

There is a way to download an assets folder when the user "install" a PWA on his device? I have about 300MB of images (map tiles) that I need to pre-cache for a user, my user ll be in an area without connection. And I would like to know if this "installation" creates some local folder that I can download my images to, or unfortunately, I need to go native...

I already tried some libs that work with my map solution (`leaflet`), but those libs only cache PNGs in `IndexedDB` in blob format, I don't think that ll be a good solution for this massive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `pre-fecth` strategy in order to ensure all the static assets are downloaded and available in the cache when the service worker is installed:

```
const mapTilesToCache = [
  '/mapFolder/',
];

const staticCacheName = 'tiles-cache';

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName)
    .then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(mapTilesToCache);
    })
  );
});
```

However keep in mind that this kind of strategy is typically used for the app shell files (much less than 300MB). If the service worker cannot download the resources you defined for the "install" phase, it will abort its installation.

Once your files are in the cache, you can serve them to the user:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        // return the file from the cache
        return response;
      }

    }).catch(error => {
      // Respond with custom offline page
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: i got it, that's what im doing now but im allowed to cache only about 50MB, because of the quota...so i believe that i need to go native...